# In map<string, int>, is it guaranteed that the int is initialized to zero?

Tags: c++, stdmap

For example, count the occurrence the words in a book, I saw somebody simply wrote:

```
map<string, int> count;
string s;
while (cin >> s) count[s]++;
```

Is this the correct way of doing so? I tested on my machine and seems so. But is the initialization to zero guaranteed? If it is not, I would imagine a code like this:

```
map<string, int> count;
string s;
while (cin >> s)
    if (count.find(s) != count.end())  count[s]++;
    else count[s] = 1;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, `operator[]` on a `std::map` will initialize the value with `T()`, which in the case of `int`, is zero.

This is documented on section 23.4.4.3 of the C++ standard:

> ```
> T& operator[](const key_type& x);
> ```
>
> *Effects*: If there is no key equivalent to `x` in the map, inserts
>   `value_type(x, T())` into the map.